# CLion new C++ Class file template

Tags: c++, ide, clion, file-templates

CLion has file template to generate C++ Class, which generates source file and header. In my project I have handler classes that have same code part, and i want to generate them by file templates. And templates that i created can't do this:

1. Set file names for class MyHandlerClass i want my_handler_class.cpp and .hpp
2. From one class name i want to generate 2 files header and source, don't know how to do that.
3. I also want to have string like MyClass -> my-class, found function `$lowercaseAndDash($NAME)` but don't know why its not works

I have template for header:

```
#pragma once
// includes

namespace handlers {

class ${NAME}: public Parent {
  public:
  // methods
};

}
```

I tried to solve first problem by setting the file name like this: `#set ($FILE_NAME = "test_class.hpp")`. But i don't know hot to set CamelCase to snake, and this don't works.

Also find in [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/template-variables.html) function to snake case, but its not works for me in file template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Its impossible to change file name from template. When you create a C++ Class, you set **class name** and **select file name encoding**. When you **create file** from template its **saves file with your file name**. I found solution this way, enter file_name (in snake case), and with Velocity create CamelCaseName for class name:

   `#set( $CamelCaseName = "" )`

   `#set( $part = "" )`

   `#foreach($part in $NAME.split("_"))`

   `#set( $CamelCaseName = "${CamelCaseName}$part.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()$part.substring(1).toLowerCase()" )`

   `#end`
2. Its impossible to generate 2 files from one click like it do C++ Class template. I have to templates, and use them both.
3. This function is for liveTemplates, for FileTemplate i used velocity: `#set( $NeededString = $NAME.replaceAll('_', '-') )`

   To include header file from cpp use `#[[#include]]# "${NAME}.hpp"`